# Moving only numbers from one column to adjacent column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with text and $ amounts in column A, but in different rows. I would like to move only the $ amounts to the adjacent column B. For example, the column looks like this.

The Pool Apache
Frontis

$2,000
1

White River
xiv

$3,000
1

So I would want to move **only** the $ amounts to the adjacent column.

I'm pretty sure this could be done with a formula, and have read a number of similar posts, but can't quite work out the correct formula.

Comment: Is the cell formatted as Currency/Accounting, or does it actually have a dollar sign in there?  Also, will the cell under the dollar amount always be `1`? (I'm trying to determine how you know there's a dollar amount by formula, since this could easily be solved with a simple `if()` statement).

Comment: @brucewayne the if statement is the simple part, it the condition check that is the harder part.  That and as you stated knowing what format the data is stored.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the help. The cel is formatted as currency. Although it doesn't have to be if that would make it easier. I could just reformat all of the cels in the column to general, etc. The cel under the dollar amount does change. Approximately every 75 dollar amount entries the number will go up by one, up to the number 20.

Comment: As @ForwardEd mentioned, the trick is determining which cell is a Dollar value, and which aren't.  Is it safe to say that all cells in column A that are `Numeric` and a length greater than 1, are dollar values?  Or perhaps they're all the same length? Do you see what we're getting at?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. The numbers below the dollar amounts are formatted as "general" and have a maximum length of 2, meaning that the numbers range from 1 to 20. The dollar amounts have a minimum of 3 leghtn

Comment: woops...hit return too soon. The dollar amounts have a minimum length of 3, meaning in the hundreds of dollars. I should also note that because the dollar amount cels are currently formatted as currency they look like this "$3,000.00"

Comment: in terms of cell formatting, for the most part excel formulas really don't look at cell formatting if I understand correctly.  Now as BruceWayne pointed out very nicely in his VBA approach, VBA can look at formatting applied to a cell.  The main thing with formula was being able to identify what distinguishes your money number from a standard number.  Not always possible.  in your case you found three ways.

Comment: Money will have a length of at least 3.  Not a fan of this one as 1.2 is three characters but not where you want to be.  You also said money would be a minimum of 100 that works really well.  The other you said was the other numbers would be max 20.  you can use either of those two numbers as check points.

Answer (score 2):

```
=if(isnumber(A1),A1,"")
```

That will pull only numbers to the adjacent columns which means the $2000 and the 1 would come over.  So assuming the pattern is blank cell, money amount, integer blank cell we can modify the formula to:

```
=if(AND(isnumber(A2),A1=""),A2,"")
```

Now that formula has to go in cell B2 and gets copied down.  Its limitation is that the first A1 can't be the money.

Now if the money is stored as a string life might get a little easier.

```
=IF(left(A1,1)="$",A1,"")
```

That formula can go in B1 and get copied down.  That will pull all strings starting with $ over to the adjacent column.  And the icing on the cake is if you need to turn that string into a number we wold toss in a few more functions to the previous formula and wind up with:

```
=IF(left(A1,1)="$",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"$",""),",",""),"")
```

#### UPDATE

After coming back from lunch and seeing the new info, I agree with Bruces statement and will give two options.  The first is based on length of the value in A1, and the second will be on the breakpoint of 20.

```
=if(AND(isnumber(A1),len(A1)>2),A1,"")
```

OR

```
=if(AND(isnumber(A1),A1>20),A1,"")
```

OR

```
=if(AND(isnumber(A1),A1>=100),A1,"")
'I prefer this one as it is a direct check on your criteria for money being no less than $100
```

All those fomulas can be placed in B1 and copied down.

Comment: Probably want to add to `and(isnumber(a2),A1="")` a check if the length is greater than one (it looks like some of his cells have just `1`).

Comment: Hi Bruce, Your second solution worked. Thank you. It is now showing the dollar amounts in column B. Is there a way to divorce the formula from the figure? I ask because I now that the dollar amounts are segregated in column B I want to copy them into another worksheet. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Bruce & Forward. I used the first solution that I could get to work, which was this one: =if(AND(isnumber(A2),A1=""),A2,""). Per my comment above, I was able to figure out a solution without needing to copy the dollar amounts into another worksheet. Thanks again for all of your help. Saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 2):

Until we can determine a way to detect which cells are currency or not with a formula, you can use you can use this Function, if a VBA solution is okay. (Note: Place in a Workbook Module)

```
Function is_Currency(ByVal target As Range)
If VarType(target) = vbCurrency Then
    is_Currency = target.Value
Else
    is_Currency = ""
End If
End Function
```

Edit: Per @ForwardEd, you could also create this `isCurrency()` UDF, and use it like `isNumeric()`:

```
Public Function isCurrency(ByVal Target as Range) as Boolean
If varType(Target) = vbCurrency Then isCurrency = TRUE
End Function
```

Then just put this in your column B: `=If(isCurrency(A1),A1,"")`.

Comment: I thought you were going to make IsCurrency UDF a Boolean and have it work the same way isnumber, istext, iserror.  you went more the IFERROR style. nice work.  short and simple

Comment: @ForwardEd - Good idea. I just went with the above so it pulls the data too, saving a step. (I am guessing you were expecting more of `=If(isCurrency(A1),A1,"")`? I like it - I'll add that.

Comment: You can also go the route of =IFCURRENCY(A1,False Result) but I thinks the IsCurrency is the better logical check.